# How can I force the user to go to Login before going to other component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-router-dom

How can I make the admin go to login first before going to other components? So I've been getting an error about

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'isAdmin')

I know where this came from, it's from my

> const admin = useSelector((state) => state.user.currentUser.isAdmin)

I was thinking that forcing the admin to redirect to other page, but when I try to use ternary operator, the program itself already calls the useSelector.

Is there any way I can approach this problem?

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import './App.css'
// import Sidebar from './components/sidemenu/Sidebar'
import Home from './pages/home/Home'
import Login from './pages/login/Login'
// import NewProduct from './pages/newProduct/NewProduct'
// import NewUser from './pages/newUser/NewUser'
// import ProductList from './pages/product/ProductList'
// import Product from './pages/productItem/Product'
// import User from './pages/user/User'
// import UserList from './pages/userList/UserList'
function App() {
  const admin = useSelector((state) => state.user.currentUser.isAdmin)
  // const admin = false
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/">{admin ? <Home /> : <Login />}</Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: const admin = useSelector(
     state => ({
      admin : state.user.currentUser.isAdmin
    }),
    shallowEqual
  );

https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make your code safe.

For modern js you could use the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

```
const admin = useSelector((state) => state.user?.currentUser?.isAdmin)
```

A more traditional approach to do the same thing

```
const admin = useSelector((state) => state.user && state.user.currentUser && state.user.currentUser.isAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first check if `currentUser` exists.
If `currentUser = null` that means user is not authenticated and you can redirect them to `Login`

```js
function App() {
  const isLoggedIn = Boolean(useSelector((state) => state.user.currentUser))
  const admin = isLoggedIn ? useSelector((state) => state.user.currentUser.isAdmin) : false
  
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/">{admin ? <Home /> : <Login />}</Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use react hooks to handle authentication handling in all components.

for example you have context provider like this :

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export const AuthContext = createContext();

const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
     const [{ user, isLogin, isAdmin }, updateStatus] = useState({ isLogin: false, isAdmin: false });

  // some functions to updates states

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isLogin && /* user is not in login page */) {
      // redirect to login page
    }
  }, [isLogin])

  if (!isLogin || !isAdmin)
    return <></>
  }

  return (
     <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, isAdmin }}>{children} 
  </AuthContext.Provider>
}
```

(this context is very basic)

and you can wrap this provider in app.js

Answer (score 0):

You can change

```
const admin = useSelector((state) => state.user.currentUser.isAdmin)
```

to

```
const admin = useSelector((state) => state.user?.currentUser?.isAdmin)
```

to fix this issue. It definitely works.